# The plugin `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter

The plugin `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise,consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs

IM having this problem in my project and i dont have the "flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle" to remove it or to fix it .

please help !!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to pubs.yml file and add this dependency :

```
dependencies:
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.0
```

//this version will support